# Example calculations for euler characterstics of compact closed 3d surface.

Tags: general-topology

This is an incredibly stupid question to ask, but could someone walk me through the calculation of the euler characteristic for a few compact surfaces? I understand the v - e + f formula, but I don't really know where I should be getting v, e and f from. If someone could walk me through a one or two (preferable with pictures) that would be wonderful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can define the $n$-th Betti number $b_n$ as the rank of the $n$-th singular homology group. The Euler characteristic is then $\sum^\infty_{k=0}(-1)^kb_k$. You seem like a visual learner, and so I will add that the singular homology counts, for dimension $n$, the $n$-dimensional holes of the $3$-dimensional surface.

The Euler characteristic of any closed odd-dimensional manifold is $0$. See Richeson, D., Euler's Gem, Princeton, 2008 (p. 261).